# Issue: Time is not in sync between Ubuntu and Windows 8

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8, time

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 dual booting with Windows 8.1. Recently I am noticing  that whenever I boot alternative OS the time is not the same i.e. When I switch from Ubuntu to Windows, system time in Windows gets delayed by some hours. But if I correct it and boot again to Windows, the time displayed is right one.

Similarly, when I boot into Ubuntu, the time is delayed once its corrected its alright the next time.

I am using Grub bootloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Ubuntu uses "UTC" Rather than "Local time" by default, this can be fixed by opening a terminal and running `sudo nano /etc/default/rcS` and changing `UTC=yes` to `UTC=no`

Comment: Also, reboot to windows and readjust the time if it isn't fixed after this and it should be fine on both systems.

Comment: Thank you. I have made the changes. Have to restart to find out if it works or not.